# importing python file into python setup

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am attempting to start writing a script that will query IBM qradar and return the results. 
IBM have provided a number of sample scripts which i intend to use. All of these however use an 'apiclient' module which IBM provides on its github page.The link to this is below:

https://github.com/ibm-security-intelligence/api-samples/tree/7.2.8/modules

There is no setup.py file to 'install' this into python 3 . How can i get these modules 'installed'? 
I tried copying the .py files into python_Directory/Tools/Scripts and then using the standard import modulename but this did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the .py files in `Scripts`. Put them in `Lib`.